# Cannot convert NSData stored in Parse.com to NSString?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

guys
I need to store a video into Parse and I am doing it like this:

```
let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL)
self.videoFile = PFFile(data: videoData)

self.videoFile.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded, error) -> Void    in
}
```

The data is successfully stored into Parse. Then I am getting it like this:

```
var videoFile:PFFile! = object[kParseUserVideo] as PFFile

                if let currentVideoFile = videoFile {

                    videoFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in

                        var videoString:NSString! = NSString(data: data, encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding)

                        if let videoS = videoString {

                            let url = NSURL(string: videoS)

                            println(url)

                        } else {

                            println("ERROR!")
                        }

                        }, progressBlock: { (progress) -> Void in


                    })
                }
```

In the completion block I always receive the data but when trying to converted it to NSString, it is always nil. I think that maybe the encoding is the problem but nothing works. Thank you!

Comment: `NSUTF8StringEncoding` would be the standard guess but if nothing works then that's beside the point. Why are you expecting to receive a string from Parse as data when Parse does strings natively? Has the data come from an unusual source? If so then what does that source say about encoding?

Comment: I converted the data to String and tried to save it into Parse but it goes over the limit of 128 kb. Also the recomended way is to save it as a PFFile object, not as a String (when we have audio, video or another kind of file).  Most of the examples and the tutorials are about images where they do something like:
let image = UIImage(imageWithData:data) but for a video we do not have such constructor, so I need the string from the data to make NSURL and to play the video this way.

Comment: To confirm, you'd like to encode the contents of a video file as an NSString?  Why don't you cut parse out and simplify the question?   On line one, get NSData from a video file URL.  On line two encode it as an NSString.  My guess is that you've got an iOS issue (not parse), maybe that the video file size is in a lucky range -- small enough to hold in memory as NSData, but bumping into memory limit as NSString.

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions:

Solution 1:

```
                var videoFile:PFFile! = object[kParseUserVideo] as PFFile

                videoFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in

                    var videoString:NSString! = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

                    let url = NSURL(string: videoString)

                })
```

Solution 2:

```
                var videoFile:PFFile! = object[kParseUserVideo] as PFFile

                if let currentVideoFile = videoFile {

                    if currentVideoFile.url != nil {

                        let urlFromParse = NSURL(string: currentVideoFile.url!)

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
var returnData : NSString = NSString(data: responseData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation if you wish to load a pdf or other UIView data types into a webView in swift.

```
          var pdfSelected = PFObject(className: "TestDataString")
                var pdfOutput:PFFile! = dataDownload?.objectForKey("pdfName") as! PFFile
                if let currentPDF = pdfOutput{
                    if currentPDF.url != nil{
                        let urlFromParse = NSURL(string: currentPDF.url!)
                        var request = NSURLRequest(URL:urlFromParse!)
                        self.webPresentation.loadRequest(request)
                    }
                }
```